# ipyparallel parallel function calls example in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to use ipyparallel from jupyter lab to execute two functions in parallel. Could someone please give me an example of how this should be done? For example, running these two functions at the same time:

```
import time

def foo():
    print('foo')
    time.sleep(5)

def bar():
    print('bar')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first you will need to ensure that `ipyparallel` is installed and an `ipycluster` is running - [instructions here](https://ipython-books.github.io/59-distributing-python-code-across-multiple-cores-with-ipython/).

Once you have done that, here is some adapted code that will run your two functions in parallel:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client()

def foo():
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'foo'

def bar():
    import time
    time.sleep(10) 
    return 'bar'  

res1 = rc[0].apply(foo)
res2 = rc[1].apply(bar)
results = [res1, res2]

while not all(map(lambda ar: ar.ready(), results)):
    pass

print(res1.get(), res2.get())
```

N.B. I removed the print statements as you can't call back from the child process into the parent Jupyter session in order to print, but we can of course return a result - I block here until both results are completed, but you could instead print the results as they became available